# How to use qt-component OpacityMask

Tags: qt, qml, qt-quick

There is a question [How to hide an image using transparent rectangle in QML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44165697/how-to-hide-an-image-using-transparent-rectangle-in-qml)

The accepted answer is to use OpacityMask.
I created a qml file follow this answer, but didn't get the expected result.
Is there anything wrong in my codes?

```
import QtQuick 2.5
import QtQuick.Controls 1.4
import QtGraphicalEffects 1.0

ApplicationWindow {
    visible: true
    width: 1280
    height: 800
    title: qsTr("Hello World")

    Rectangle {
        id: background
        anchors.fill: parent
        color: "black"
    }

    Image
    {
        id:underlyingImage
        width: 1204
        height: 682

        fillMode: Image.PreserveAspectCrop
        layer.enabled: true
        layer.effect: OpacityMask {
            maskSource: hiding_rect
        }

        source:"qrc:/timg.jpg"
    }
    Rectangle
    {
        id:hiding_rect
        width: underlyingImage.width/2
        height: underlyingImage.height/2
        color: "yellow"
    }
}
```

[the result picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o6sY7.jpg)

Comment: what do you expect?

Comment: @Paul I expect the area of hiding_rect in underlyingImange to be transparent, and I can see the black background through hiding_rect. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not familiar with the approach suggested in the other question.
However, following the approach suggested in the documentation (http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtgraphicaleffects-opacitymask.html), this works:

```
Window {
    visible: true
    width: 1280
    height: 800
    title: qsTr("Hello World")

    Rectangle {
        id: background
        anchors.fill: parent
        color: "black"
    }

    Image
    {

        anchors.centerIn: parent

        id:underlyingImage
        width: 1204
        height: 682

        fillMode: Image.PreserveAspectCrop
        source:"file:///tmp/timg.jpg"
        visible: false
    }

    Item {
        id:hiding_rect
        anchors.fill: underlyingImage
        visible: false
        Rectangle
        {
            anchors.left: parent.left
            anchors.top: parent.top
            width: underlyingImage.width/2
            height: underlyingImage.height/2
            color: Qt.rgba(1,1,1,1)
            z: underlyingImage.z + 1
        }
    }




    OpacityMask {
        anchors.fill: underlyingImage
        source: underlyingImage
        maskSource: hiding_rect
    }
}
```